# Android: Cannot Find IInAppBillingService 3.0 from PacketManager

Tags: android

Using Eclipse 3.7.2
Android SDK 4.2.2
Android Ver 4.1.2 S3 and 4.2.2 S4
InAppBillingService 3
This is a Java C++ app

I followed the directions in the Preparing Your In-app Billing Application document.  I imported IInAppBillingService.aidl in com.myapp directory.  On compile the jave file IInAppBillingService is created in gen.com.myapp.

So far so good.

When I create the Intend as below:
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");

It Package manager will find it and bind:

```
    if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
        // service available to handle that Intent
        mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

On `IInAppBillingService.isBillingSupported`, I get a failure:

```
08-28 15:43:31.402: W/Parcel(2670): **** enforceInterface() expected     
'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService' but read 
'com.myapp.IInAppBillingService'
```

I have tried various other intents:

//        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("gen.com.myapp.InAppBillingService.BIND");
//        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("InAppBillingService.BIND");
//        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("IInAppBillingService.BIND");
//        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.IInAppBillingService.BIND");
//        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.InAppBillingService.BIND");

I can find nothing but `com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND`

Also the import in IabHelper is

`import com.sensorscope.IInAppBillingService;`

and it is found by Eclipse

What am I missing????